# Need to capitalize first letter of piglatin word

Tags: python-3.x

So my problem is asking me to capitalize the first letter of a piglatin program, and I have the part that outputs the piglatin word.

It works correctly to output the word, but my code for the capitalization doesn't work. But, there aren't any errors, just that it doesn't capitalize the first letter.

```
def english_to_piglatin(word):
    '''english_to_piglatin(word) -> string
    Translates word into Pig Latin.'''
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':  # check if the first letter is a vowel
        return word + 'way'
    # word begins with a consonant
    consonants = ''  # keep track of consonants at start of word
    while len(word) > 0 and word[0] not in 'aeiou':
        consonants += word[0]  # add the consonant
        word = word[1:]  # remove the first letter from word
        if word.isupper == False: #check if the first letter is uppercase 
            word = word[1:].upper() #capitalize the word
    return word + consonants + 'ay' #add the ay

print(english_to_piglatin("python")) #outputs "onpythay" instead of "Onpythay"
```

No error messages, and in this case it should output "Onpythay" instead of "onpythay" for the word: python.

Comment: `word.isupper` is a _function_. Comparing it to a Boolean doesn't make much sense, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if word.isupper == False` is the code you have to fix. This is because `isupper` is a function. You're using it as if it's a variable. You just need to run it as a function to fix it.

However, after running your code, if we change that, it makes this: `pTHONay`

What we'll need to do is change the position of that code. Therefore, it turns into this:

```py
def english_to_piglatin(word):
    '''english_to_piglatin(word) -> string
    Translates word into Pig Latin.'''
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':  # check if the first letter is a vowel
        return word + 'way'
    # word begins with a consonant
    consonants = ''  # keep track of consonants at start of word
    while len(word) > 0 and word[0] not in 'aeiou':
        consonants += word[0]  # add the consonant
        word = word[1:]  # remove the first letter from word
    pigLatin = word + consonants + 'ay'
    return pigLatin.capitalize()#add the ay

print(english_to_piglatin("python")) #outputs "onpythay" instead of "Onpythay"
```

Essentially, I removed the if statement where it turns the middle letters into capital letters, and used `.capitalize()` to capitalize the final product.

Comment: If this question solved your problem, please mark it as solved to indicate this question has been solved!